# Unencrypted wifi - what applications are safe?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, encryption

A few places I frequent have unencrypted wifi. My understanding of this is that any packets sent between my laptop and the router are not encrypted, but how do applications factor into this?

The 3 main things I do when connected to those wifi networks are:

1. Sync dropbox using the desktop client
2. Check email using thunderbird
3. Access websites that are protected by SSL/TLS

Are those activities safe to perform over unencrypted wifi? I'm guessing each of those use their own form of encryption when communicating with their respective servers, but does that kick in before or after my unencrypted communication with the router?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypted Wifi means the comms between your laptop and wifi access point is not encrypted.
Sycing dropbox, emails and visited Sites is the Comms between your laptop and dropbox, same to email and ssl sites which are encrypted Comms. for example, dropbox uses secure protocols to transfer/ sync files for example sftp instead of ftp. It all depend on the initial handshake when key is shared which is used to encrypt end to end communication. if dropbox is using private/ public key pair (asymmetric), this handshake is secure (most probiders use protocols that provide asymmetric handshake). however using symmetric handshake, the risk is if someone gets the key then he/ she can see your data transferring between your laptop and dropbox/ email/ sites.

Comment: I answered so I wont downvote but key elements of this answer are wrong - including: email may or may not be secure depending on protocol. imap isnt, imaps is.POP3 isnt, pop3s is.  Security does not depend on asymetric encryption - indeed in this environment symetric encryption (which implies out of band key negotiation) is actually stronger - where asymetric encryption relies on third party certs - wifi encryption does not break asymetric or symetric encryption.

Comment: @davidgo: Asymmetric encryption or key exchange does not rely on third-party certs. Even in the context of TLS, using internal PKI roots or even pinning specific self-issued certificates by fingerprint is a thing that many programs do. Many other non-TLS protocols don't even have the concept of "third-party certs" while still using asymmetric key exchange.

Comment: @grawity you are quite right - my comment is very badly worded - it should have mentioned  avoiding mitm attacks without having prior comunication with the site. (ssh keys and pgp are, of-course good example of where no ca is involved)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of Dropbox and https sites should be fine as they are end-to-end encrypted. Email wil be fine (to the limited extent it is over an encrypted connection) if the protocols used are encrypted - so imap is not secure, impaps is, likewise smtp with ssl/ tls is OK, but unencrypted smtp is not great.

That said, the risk profile of an unsecured wifi connection is probably quite different to what your pist seems to imply - specifically -

- You should assume any unencrypted communication is insecure as the connection to the AP is only 1 link in the chain - there are plenty of other intercept points in most connections - although an open AP can be an "easier in". IE you should not trust secure WIFI networks significantly more then unsecured ones.
- The point of an encrypted WIFI is more to protect the wifinetwork owner from having their resoyrce abused.
- Its a good idea to ensure you have some firewalling on your device if using an unsecured AP because its *that much easier* for someone to attack your PC through exposed ports/services.